# Execute multiple ssh commands in the same shell (programatically)

Tags: ssh

**NOTE: I'm really looking for an *SSH-y* solution here, more than *bash-y* one.**

I need to execute a series of commands over ssh, programatically. There are many ways to do this, but I can't find any that works with my constraints:

- some of the commands set variables in the shell. Therefore I dont think I can make this work using multiple shells.
- some of these variables are functions, not normal values, so I dont think I can simply serialize the output of `env` to "restore" the old environment.
- I need to access the stdout, stderr and exit code of each command separately. This makes it difficult to chain the commands using `&&` or `;`. I believe this also makes it difficult to use `screen`, because we cant reliably tell when a command finishes.
- I need real-time access to the stdout, stderr, etc so we can record when the output occurs. (I use "real-time" to mean "nowish", not "hard real-time" or anything like that).

#### Update

**Why do I need a single bash session?** Because commands may store arbitrary variables and functions in the environment. For example, it would be common to run `rvm`, which is a bash function added by a previously run command.

**Why can't I use `&&` or `;`?** Because I need the stdout and stderr or each command individually, and this would mix them.

**Why can't I use screen?** Because we want to run commands automatically, not as part of an interactive session. Consider the difficulty of this: I'd have to run the command with input form redirection, output via redirection, and then scp the results back. I'd need to echo `$?` to get the exit code. I wouldn't be able to timestamp the stderr/stdout. I wouldn't be able to timeout the command. And it would be incredibly buggy.

Comment: Please edit your question to add your script.  We can then find why env && screen and ; won't work for your script.

Comment: @Jeremy: there is no script. This is a program to run commands remotely under various configurations and store their results.

Answer (score 2):

If you need something to be able to capture output, interact with a shell session and/or interact with pty applications like `screen` you could try writing in a higher-level language's SSH library, like Ruby's [Net:SSH](http://net-ssh.github.com/ssh/v2/api/index.html).  It has a bit of a learning curve, but would accomplish everything you need, I believe.

Comment: We are using an ssh library (http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/), but I dont think that using one is sufficient information to solve the problem. Can you describe more about how we would use a single bash process for all the commands in Net:SSH?

Comment: I think Kyle has the right idea.  Perhaps a higher level language (perl,python,ruby)  would satisfy.  Each language has syntax for executing Bash scripts and *nix commands.

Comment: I've used Net::SSH for far simpler things that you're suggesting (i.e. not stringing commands together) but it appears from the API docs that you can create a "channel" object and "request a pty" at which point you can interact with the shell directly.  Seems to be some work involved in retrieving exit codes, something about parsing data.read_long.  Anyway I was just suggesting that something like this would be cleaner than a huge nasty ssh command inside of a bash script that writes out result files and concatenates them together (for this, I am speaking for experience ;]).

Comment: @Kyle: sure, I agree. I guess I'm just looking for specifics like "ptys are able to do X, channels can do Y, so you just need to Z the X and W the Y, and you should be all set".

Answer (score 2):

> I need to access the stdout, stderr and exit code of each command separately. This makes it difficult to chain the commands using && or ;.

Well, I don't know if I really recommend this, but you *could* write a shell function like this one:

```
function prefix ()
(
  PREFIX="$1"
  OUT=''
  while read -r ; do
    OUT="${OUT}${PREFIX}${REPLY}"$'\n'
  done
  echo "$OUT"
)

function run_cmd ()
{
  echo "Running command << $@ >> . . ."
  (
    ( ( "$@" ; echo "\$?: $?" >&3 ) | prefix 'STDOUT: ' >&3 ) 2>&1 \
    | prefix 'STDERR: '
  ) 3>&1
}
```

Then if `./foo.sh bar` prints out `foo\nbar\n` to standard output and `baz\nbip\n` to standard error, and exits with code 1, then `run_cmd ./foo.sh bar` will print something like:

```
Running command << ./foo.sh bar >> . . .
$?: 0
STDOUT: foo
STDOUT: bar
STDERR: baz
STDERR: bip
```

That should let you chain a sequence of commands, provided you use `run_cmd` for all of the ones that you need STDOUT/STDERR/exit-codes for. (But since the command itself is run in five-layers-deep of subshells, you can't use `run_cmd` to run any command that needs to set environment variables for use by other commands. Hopefully you don't have any commands that *both* give output *and* set variables?)

Comment: um, yeah :( Right now, rvm does, but this is for arbitrary commands so I can't live with this problem long term :( Good answer though.

Answer (score 1):

Did you already take a look at `pssh`? It covers the most of your requirements, and with some creativity and imagination it may well help you:

- Can send the commands to multiple servers at the same time
- Is able to output in real time
- stdout and stderr can be saved to separate files
- reports you if command X at server Y succeeded or not
- can receive input from stdin and send that to servers
- has configurable timeout

And so on...

Answer (score 0):

I also believe Kyle's approach would be the most promising. If that doesn't work out, you could write your main script in a way that it goes in an endless loop where it looks for command files which it then sources and makes stdout, stderr and exit code available in a form usable for your purpose.

You would then insert the command files via an alternate channel, likely just `scp`  or something similar.